# Azure B2C Graph API: Create User with an Object ID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to create a user, via Graph API, with a predefined Object ID?  When the user invites another user via email, I want to be able to either:

1. Create the user, via Graph API, beforehand and have the user use the email invite to setup their password.  This then activates the account.
2. Upon inviting the user, generate an Object ID with the ID token.  Then, upon the user creating their account via the email invite, have the generated Object ID be used for the user to be created via Azure B2C.

Which approach would be more feasible?

Comment: Ever find a solution for pre-setting the user's object ID when creating a user via the graph API?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible

Comment: Yikes, Well thank you regardless for letting me know. I will just have to add another B2C Extension property (which is already a pain as it is) and store the ID I wanted to be the Object ID as a separate ID. Sometimes I really regret using B2C honestly

Answer (score 1):

No - it's a GUID, randomly assigned when the user is created.

The former. This is essentially a version of the [magic link flow](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link).